# invalidate refreshed entry in Guava CacheLoader

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have a Guava Cache with a `CacheLoader`. There is an external condition I track in a Thread, and if this happens I want to `refresh()` all entries asynchronously. For this reason I do not use `invalidateAll()` since the next `get()` would have to wait for load to succeed.

Instead I iterate over the keys contained in the cache and `refresh(k)` all of them, as I could not find a refreshAll() method. Here is the code (but not really related to the question):

```
    Set<ResourceLoaderKey> keys = resourceLoaderCache.asMap().keySet();
    for(ResourceLoaderKey k : keys)
    {
        resourceLoaderCache.refresh(k);
    }
```

My problem is now, that `reload()` in the CacheLoader might detect, that a resource is actually not any longer available. Currently the `reload()` throws a ResourceNotFound exception which works for the `get()` case. But it does not work for the `refresh()` case, as the old value will be served as long as the `reload()` fails.

I can now trap the not-found exception in the load/reload methods and invalidate the entry somehow, but I wonder if there is a official way to do it (returning null or a null future is logged as a warning and ignored)? It would be good to be able to remove the key/absent-value instead of keeping a placeholder object around.

Comment: similar problem here, my current solution is ugly, wish there was a supported way to do this

Answer (score 0):

A supported way to do this doesn't currently exist in guava r17.

Have you tried getting all the keys, then invalidating all, then attempting to get all the keys you had saved?

```
Set<ResourceLoaderKey> keys = resourceLoaderCache.asMap().keySet();
resourceLoaderCache.invalidateAll(keys);
for(ResourceLoaderKey k : keys) {
    resourceLoaderCache.get(k);        //or getUnchecked() whichever you prefer
}
```

That should make sure no stale values stay in the cache, and recache all values that exist.

(My problem was slightly different, I had to change my assumptions to solve mine)

Comment: I cant do that, as I dont want the regular updates for unchanged keys to hit the cache loader. Maybe I should think about calling invalidate from within the loader...

Comment: @eckes wouldn't you be hitting the cache loader anyways when refreshing all entries? how different are your load() and reload() implementations?

Comment: @eckes haha, this is even more similar to my problem than I thought, I ended up writing the async reload logic manually so that I could handle NotFoundExceptions and call .invalidate() otherwise I'd call .put() and manually write the cache entry (this was outside of the cache loader, idk where it would fit in your package)